# Pandas sort list returned by str.split()

Tags: python, string, sorting, pandas, dataframe

Given a Pandas Series of type str, I want to sort the result returned by str.split.

For example, given the Series

```
s = pd.Series(['abc,def,ghi','ghi,abc'])
```

I would like to get

```
s2 = pd.Series(['abc,def,ghi','abc,ghi'])
```

as a result.

How can I do this? I thought about something like `s.str.split(',').sort()`. However, I could find no such sort function in Pandas. Any other ideas?

Another idea would be to use the function `get_dummies`, then rearange the columns and finally do something like `join_dummies`. However, I could not find such a function `join_dummies`.

Comment: It's quite inefficient to split each row's string, sort it and re-join it. What output are you ultimately trying to get? Please show the steps after this that consume s2. Why does the sort order of distinct column names matter at all? Splitting the string and using `get_dummies()` sounds good, assuming you have a bound on the number of different string names you can get at step s2. Either way, we really need more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
In [70]: s.str.split(',').map(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x)))
Out[70]:
0    abc,def,ghi
1        abc,ghi
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function which is very useful in Pandas.

```
s.apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(','))))

0    abc,def,ghi
1        abc,ghi
```