# Sort str series by frequency

Tags: python, string, pandas

Given a Pandas Series of type str, I want to sort the result returned by str.split by their frequency.

For example, given the Series

```
s = pd.Series(['abc,def,ghi','ghi,abc'])
```

I would like to get

```
s2 = pd.Series(['abc,ghi,def','abc,ghi'])
```

as a result ('abc', 'ghi' come before 'def' because they have frequency 2 whereas 'def' has frequency 1).

Essentially, I am asking for a combination of [Pandas sort list of str.split()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987807/pandas-sort-list-of-str-split) and [Pandas count frequencies within str series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988360/pandas-count-frequencies-within-str-series/36988399?noredirect=1#comment61531350_36988399)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [71]: freq = pd.Series(s.str.split(',').sum()).value_counts()

In [72]: s.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x, key=freq.get, reverse=True)))
Out[72]:
0    abc,ghi,def
1        ghi,abc
dtype: object
```

Explanation:

```
In [73]: freq
Out[73]:
ghi    2
abc    2
def    1
dtype: int64

In [75]: sorted(['abc','def','ghi'], key=freq.get, reverse=True)
Out[75]: ['abc', 'ghi', 'def']
```

PS `abc` and `ghi` have the same weight, because of that it's unpredictable in which order they will appear in the resulting series